# Python: How to create a new dataframe with first row when a specific value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am reading csv files into python using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\csvfile.csv")
```

But the file has some summary data, and the raw data start if a value "valx" is found. If "valx" is not found then the file is useless. I would like to create news dataframes that start when "valx" is found. I have been trying for a while with no success. Any help on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pandas only accepts `skiprows` for rows to skip in the beginning. You might want to parse the file before creating the dataframe.

As an example:

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\csvfile.csv","r") as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f, newline = '')
    if any('valx' in i for i in lines):
        data = lines
```

Using the Standard Libary csv module, you can read file and check if `valx` is in the file, if it is found, the content will be returned in the `data` variable.

From there you can use the data variable to create your dataframe.